# Can I include this ReactJs project in my Electron web app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, spotify

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I am  building a web app for my class project using Electron.js. My project is all JS, CSS, and HTML code right now.

Here is the homepage of my program on codepen.

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Shant7/pen/NWLJZge)

It has an index.html page that is the login page/username for the user. Then the homepage.html page has a navigation bar where users can click on different html buttons to go to various features. The other features we have now are all made with HTML, JS, and CSS.
```

We wanted to use this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1cpb0tYV74&t=3595s to incorporate a Spotify-like feature where users can search and play music.

Here is the code for this tutorial also https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_music_player. It uses Tailwind, React, Redux, and RapidApi.

I wanted to ask if this is possible and if so do you have any tips or suggestions on how to incorporate this feature into what we already have?

I have tried looking for ways to do this in just Js, HTML, and CSS but I haven't found any tutorials that allow users to play songs which is the primary purpose of this feature.

Comment: Please include your [mcve] in the question itself. Do not circumvent site rules for posting links by marking non-code as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can do it in vanilla HTML + CSS + JS, just that it needs more work for you to work on the logic and styling of your music player.

I provide you a minimal example html page here, with a play button to play/pause an audio file from a URL. You can replace the URL or use Javascript logic to replace the src attribute within  tag to achieve Spotify-like music player on your page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Audio</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      function play() {
        var playBtn = document.getElementById("button");
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        if(audio.paused){
          audio.play();
          playBtn.value = "PAUSE"
        } else {
          audio.pause();
          playBtn.value = "PLAY"
        }
      }
    </script>

    <input id="button" type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/audio/2022/07/13/audio_75c818dbe1.mp3"></audio>

  </body>
</html>
```